# Passing a class variable with three arguments into a constructor as a parameter

Tags: java, class, arguments, parameter-passing

```
public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
    setMonth(month);
    setDay(day);
    setYear(year); }
```

**How do I go about passing Date dob variable in the Person constructor as a a parameter. Do I  **

```
public class Person { 
   private String firstName = null;
   private String lastName = null;
   public Date dateOfBirth;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Date dob) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    dob = dateOfBirth;
 }
public void setDateOfBirth(int month, int day, int year) {

dateOfBirth = new Date(month,day,year);

}
```

**I should have included the setDateOfBirth method from my Person class. Now it makes sense**

Comment: Yes you can. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Create a `Date` with `new Date(1,2,1980)` and pass that to the constructor?

Comment: So create the dob object and use methods from the other class to get the information?

Comment: Khanna111 why comment? You didnt give me any good feedback. I obviously dont know what im doing.

Comment: I understand I can create the object and give it some numbers but I need the numbers to come from Date class. So do I just do dob = new Date(setMonth(),setDay(),setYear());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So do I just do dob = new Date(setMonth(),setDay(),setYear());

No you don't have to.

The `Data` object `dob` already contains all the information you want.

Just create a `Data` object as an attribute of your `Person` class and you're done.